# Beginning learning SQL with C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

Sorry if this has been asked elsewhere, but I couldn't find a clear answer anywhere.

I have decided to begin learning to use relational databases a bit more, namely SQL. This is a major beginners question but its probably essential to get started on.

I'm basically a little confused the best practice on how to utilize SQL (or other). At college i have accessed databases (using JSON strings) for things such as mobile apps, but i have never actually designed and built a database myself, as my tutor made the mentioned database for us to access himself.

Lets say I have a C# application that holds genealogy information (i.e. families and their members) and i wanted to store each individual on a database. Would I, simply use the structure I already have but save to fields in a database instead of an xml or text document? Or does it work the other way, i.e. do I create a database with required fields then just retrieve this from the database in a c# application and manipulate the data as I so wish, so the application would be entirely different (so the c# application basically doesn't really hold/store any data and just works on whats fed from the database)?

Whats troubling me is that usually where I would store my c# objects in a dictionary or list for example, would i instead just retrieve straight from the database? or retrieve from the and store the data into a normal structure and work from there (surely this would defeat the point of fast-searching from a database)?

I may be over-thinking it slightly. Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance

Comment: You will get a lot more traction on this question if you ask it over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ (stackoverflow is one of many sites in the stackexchange)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Would I, simply use the structure I already...

or

> do I create a database with required fields...

I think that is the crux of your question.

## Starting from the database

For me, when building an application that uses a backend database, an Entity-Relationship diagram is pretty crucial.  I found quite a nice little tutorial for you here: http://www.sum-it.nl/cursus/dbdesign/english/index.php3 but you can easily find one that suits your learning style.  The key point is that you are trying to model the problem domain (the real world out there that needs your application) in a way that your application can somehow capture. Once you have an E-R diagram of related tables, it is easier to figure out the details. Using SQL Management Studio for SQL Server 2008 (Express edition) you can create a few basic tables and build the E-R diagram right there and have it generate relationships for you. You can then, at your leisure, examine the SQL used to achieve that and refine accordingly.

Personally, I always start by examining the problem domain, then I build the E-R diagram, then I build the database.  I start building the C# application when I'm reasonably confident the database reflects the problem domain.

## Starting from your C# application

However, what really matters is that you model the real world in a meaningful and effective way. In your case you already have a starting point in structures you've created in C# and you can use them to give you a starting point to build the E-R diagram.   If you find it easier to get a C# application going and then build a database that reflects it, that should be fine. Perhaps you already have an approach that helps you capture the problem domain effectively. It's an iterative process whatever you do: building the C# code might reveal problems with the underlying database design and vice versa.

## Diagramming - E-R or UML?

I'm personally convinced that this whole business is so complicated that you really need some diagrams.

- to visualise your database, use an E-R diagram
- to visualise your C# application use a UML class diagram

As you head towards a working application, you'll see how these 2 diagrams begin to match or at least reflect eash other pretty closely. In both cases, (entities or classes) understanding the relationship between objects will be really important when you query the database because it is crucial to understand relationships between tables (especially using 1-to-many relationships to resolve a complex many-to-many relationship) and various techniques for joining tables in queries (INNER or OUTER joins etc) No matter how clever your C# application is, you will at some point need to understand at least some of the complexities of the SQL language - and it is easier if you can refer to an E-R diagram.

## Where to store?

> Whats troubling me is that usually where I would store my c# objects in a dictionary or list for example, would i instead just retrieve straight from the database?

In the database, without a doubt.  A C# class called Family would have a property FamilyName, say, with a setter method built in.  If you discover a spelling mistake and want to change the name, the setter method would open a connection to the database, run an UPDATE query with the specified family name, (and probably the family id) as a parameter, and update the underlying field accordingly. Retrieving data would involve running a SELECT query etc.

## Conclusion

Do some tutorials on how to examine a problem domain, create an entity-relationship diagram and build a set of related tables based on the diagram. I'm convinced that way you'll find it much easier to keep track of the C# classes that you build to communicate with the backend database.

Here's an example of a simple E-R diagram for families and their members:

[image: simple e-r diagram]

To begin with you might think members and family could be in one table, but then you discover that creates a lot of duplication so you separate that out into family and member table with a one-to-many relationship, but then you realise that, through marriage for instance, people can belong to more than one family and you need to create a many-to-many relationship.  I think the E-R diagram is the best place to work out that kind of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what your structures look like or how your DB will be designed this is hard to answer. But you should be able to use existing data structures, and just pipe the data from the database instead of the XML file.

Look into [Linq-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386927.aspx), C# has a strong library to interact with SQL. May be a bit confusing at first, but very powerful once you learn it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not particularly looking to solve a specific problem, i was more asking for tips on when is best to do which action - so I don't wish to linger on the example given :) 

So, to just save the data to the database instead of an XML file would the database just need to consist of fields that would match the corresponding objects. A very simple example would be to save a familyMember(int,string,string) C# object then the database should include a table that will hold an integer and two string values, and i just add the data to the table accordingly?

Comment: Yup, that will work pretty nicelt. Linq-to-SQL will then help you to create the C# data objects from the data in the DB. Its also easy to update, add, delete, select objects and more.

Comment: Ok, I shall have a play with doing that then. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I am right you are asking also if you should retrieve all the records from the database and store them as objects in a collection or retrieve selected records from the database and use the dataset results without placing them in a purpose defined structure.

I tend to select the records I want from the database and then load the results into my purpose defined classes / structures. This allows you to add your manipulation methods to the class holding a record result etc. without needing to take in dataset results to each method. However you will find yourself doing singular updates all the time when a batch update might be more efficient... if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that was what i was mainly asking - thanks. I like the idea of loading into purpose defined structures much better. I was just a bit concerned it could of been considered a bad way to go about things because i guess it may be slower to retrieve from the database and then store into a structure? I guess it may not be too significant

Comment: The most significant time will be the transfer of data to and from the database. Placing data into variables of a structure will probably be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at entity frameworks code first. If your data structures are classes in your application there are techniques to use that to create your database schema from that. As far as the data. Store it in your database and populate your lists and dictionaries with it. Or populate list of class genealogy individual with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own data classes, there's a free tutorial [here](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s297/data-classes.htm) written by myself.  What I would definitely not to is use the data sources in ASP.NET, as these wizards are the Barty Crouches of the ASP.NET world - they appear good, but turn out to be evil, as inevitably you'll want to be able to tweak them and you won't understand how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.